# Automatically Change Sheet Reference in formula

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I have hundreds of sheets, with one master sheet, and I have this formula in my master sheet

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!M$2:M$11,"No")>0, "Y", "N")&COUNTIF(Sheet2!M$2:M$4,"No")&COUNTIF(Sheet2!M$2:M$7,"No")&COUNTIF(Sheet2!M$2:M$11,"No")
```

which basically grabs the number of yes or nos in a column from the referenced sheet, in this case 'Sheet2', and returns Yes, if there are multiple NOs in the column, and the other arguments just return the count of NOs in the cell ranges.

I just want to drag down the formula in the column it is located in, and have the Sheet reference change from Sheet2 to Sheet3, Sheet4, and so on, but it simply copies it down the column. I've tried looking into it, got some hints with using `INDIRECT` but I'm returning errors left and right that I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

EDIT: sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jcbjUs4Ho0LlXF-Olu5NkEw4THqaA0nB5dduYKfx5S8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I looked at your data. So cell `J3` looks at `Sheet3`, `J4` at `Sheet4`. Is that the general pattern? So you have as many sheets as there are rows in the sheet "keyword" ?

Comment: @PeterK. exactly man! Was hoping for a solution that I can just drag down the formula. Been having trouble to easily reference the sheets. 

EDIT: accidentally pressed enter. I have to create the succeeding sheets first, that will take some time, but it would suck if I had to manually edit the formula to fit "sheet3", "sheet4" and so on in the formula.

Comment: See my comment below, but I will formulate in a separate answer.

Comment: @PeterK. I actually tried that and applied it to my current formula, did not give me errors! But I don't think it was able to reference to the other sheet/s.

    `=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet" & "!" & M$2:M$11 & ROW()-1),"No")>0, "Y", "N")&COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet" & M$2:M$11 & "!" & ROW()-1),"No")&COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet" & M$2:M$11 & "!" & ROW()-1),"No")&COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet" & M$2:M$11 & "!" & ROW()-1),"No")`

Comment: See the formula in my answer, which is different than what you tried to do. The `ROW()` just gives you the row number of the formula, so in cell `J3` this will give `3`. As this references to Sheet2, you have to subtract 1.

Comment: @PeterK. right! Didn't know Row()-1 actually worked, was thinking somewhere along this line as I was researching how to. Thank you, again! I marked your comment as a solution.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `Sheet2!M$2:M$11` with the following:
`INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()-1&"!M$2:M$11")`

You have of course to replace the `M$2:M$11` with the respective range references.

Comment: Oh, wow, I was on the right track with my attempt. This worked perfectly my man!

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used below formula to count "No's" using a sheet reference from a cell. Try it out:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet" & A1 & "!" & "A:A");"No")>0;"Y";"N")
```

You can change the column range to suit your need - I just used column "A" in each sheet and cell "A1" with the sheet reference, in the above case A1 contained the number 2 referring to "Sheet2".

Comment: Hmmm, I;m afraid I might have confused you. my formula at the top works as intended, the only 'problem' I have right now, is I wish I can just easily drag down a column the formula and have Sheet2, automatically change to Sheet3, since each sheet I have contains identical data, in exactly the same rows just that each sheet has a different name.

Comment: @Mandirigma But that is what the `INDIRECT` formula does. In the answer above, if `A1` contains `2`and `A2` contains `3` if you drag down the formula it will search the value on the targeted sheet.

Comment: @PeterK right, I just mentioned it as a part of a possible solution. But in my spreadsheet,I have mulitple sheets. Let me edit my post with a sample of a part of my data.

Comment: could also change `A1` to `ROW(A1)+1`

Comment: @ForwardEd I asked OP to further clarify his question. In any case, based on the sample spreadsheet, it should be `ROW()-1` . In this case you actually do not need the reference to `A1`, just to the row of the formula itself is sufficient.

Comment: @PeterK. I thought row() was volatile and row(A1) was not, but I could totally be wrong in that understanding.  Lots of ways to do things, just need to pick one that works and go with it.